# Using more than 2 marker presets

Tags: aframe, ar.js

I want to use 3 markers in a script. I've started to use Kanji and Kiro marker preset without problem.
When i've started to add a third marker (a pattern with letterA.patt file via ar.js url), google chrome (and firefox) complained about a memory problem !
The only solution founded was to modify aframe-ar.js and added letterA as marker preset, like Kiro and Kanji.
Question1: what about that memory problem with my pattern ?
Question2: why not added more marker preset (letterD...) by default in aframe-ar.js ?

Best regards,

Emmanuel

Answer (score 0):

Not really the right platform for this question. You can use any number of markers that you want, you're not limited to just two. The AR.js preset might be limited but you can add your own markers with a .patt file. You can create your AR.js ready tag using the [ARjs marker generator](https://jeromeetienne.github.io/AR.js/three.js/examples/marker-training/examples/generator.html) or by uploading your model and image target to the [echoAR platform](https://console.echoar.xyz) and then download the image marker.
After you get you .patt file you can add it to your scene like so:

```
    <a-marker type='pattern' url='./<path to your .patt>'>
```

Inside your marker just add whatever you would do in a preset marker, just don't forget to close the marker tag.